# Nested foreach to echo a key from sub-array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo the value stored in key = 'Tipo' from each sub-array.

```
foreach ($palabras as $key => $palabra) {
    foreach ($palabra as $key2 => $meaning) {
        echo $palabra[$key2]['Tipo'];
        }
}
```

I'm sure my error is pretty simple, but I'm not sure what it is. The problem is that I get random characters instead of just the values.

Just so you know this is the original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Palabra] => juan
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Palabra] => es
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Raiz] => ser
                [Tipo] => verbo1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Raiz] => ser
                [Tipo] => verbo2
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Palabra] => un
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Tipo] => articulo-indeterminado
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Palabra] => adjetivo
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Tipo] => Clase
                [Clase] => Adjetivo
            )
     )
)
```

And this is what I get with my code:

`jeverbo1verbo2uarticulo-indeterminadoaClase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$palabras[0]['palabra'] ='juan';
$palabras[1]['palabra'] ='es';
$palabras[1][0]['tipo']= 'verbo1';
$palabras[1][1]['tipo']= 'verbo2';
$palabras[2]['palabra'] ='blah';
$palabras[2][0]['tipo']= 'verb03';
$palabras[3]['palabra'] ='wha';
$palabras[3][0]['tipo']= 'adjectivo';
$palabras[3][1]['tipo']= 'verbo4';

print_r($palabras);

foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
        foreach ($palabra as $key=>$parto) {
                if (is_numeric($key)) {
                        echo $parto['tipo'] . "<br>";
                }
        }
}
```

http://www.ideone.com/cXVAe

Comment: thanks, is_numeric fixed the issues. Changed it to work with the given array